# Emote shown as plain text instead of emote itself

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, interaction

I made a command as "text" command, and wanted to also make a slash command using code I made, but  even tho it's the same code, emoji works for "text" command, and is shown as plain text when trying to add it in interaction!

Here is the part of my code:

```
const embed = new MessageEmbed()
embed.addField('Badges', '<:HSE:emote_id>', true);
interaction.reply({embeds: [embed], ephemeral: false})
```

And I'm sure ID and name is corrent because I copied it from "text" command where it works just fine, but instead of emoji I only see `:HSE:`! What can I do about it?

Comment: @Aci actual ID, obviously, lol

Comment: hmm that's strange, from the code you provided above I'm pretty sure it should show the emoji.

Comment: How bout you put some text for a test, eg:`You got <:HSE:emote_id>`

Comment: @IHZAQSTORM33 nah, it doesn't help

Comment: @MegaMix_Craft Did you put \ before emoji, (I'm pretty sure you does, just to make sure)

Comment: @IHZAQSTORM33 no, as I said before, I **copied** my embed code from a command where it works